# ¿Cómo mantener la sesión abierta después de cerrar el navegador, y volver a abrirlo, con PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer que cuando el usuario cierre el navegador la sesión se mantenga abierta por un tiempo determinado, para que cuando vuelva a entrar lo redirija a la página, pero por alguna razón al cerrar el navegador completamente elimina la sesión, haciendo imposible validar. Aquí el código:

```
public static function login ($data) {
  
    $user = Clear::Clearvars($data["user"]);
    $pass = Clear::Clearvars($data["pass"]);
    $query = Model::login($user, $pass);
    if (is_array($query)) {
        self::start_session($query);
    }else {
        echo json_encode("0");
    }
}

public static function start_session($query) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user"] = $query["user"];
}

public static function verify_session_index() {
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
        ControllerView::renderview("admin_panel");
    }
}

Routes::set("index",function() {  
Login_admin::verify_session_index();
Controller::renderview('index');
});
```

Es lo único que me tiene loco, ya que cuando se ingresa a la página lo primero que hace es pasar por el index, por eso tengo que validar si tiene una sesión abierta, pero como dije anteriormente esta se elimina cuando cierro el navegador, mas no la pestaña, lo cual me hace imposible validarlo. He pensado en usar cookies pero el tiempo de vida de la cookie empieza a correr aún con el navegador abierto, lo cual también es imposible.

Comment: Puedes guardarla en una cookie así como menciona @Israel, pero en lo personal no te lo recomendaría porque estarías exponiendo tu pagina a un posible ataque

Answer (score 0):

Es el comportamiento por defecto de la sesión. No obstante puede definir el tiempo de vida de la sesión antes de iniciarla.
Siguiendo la documentación de [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

```
$sessionTime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 1 año de duración
session_set_cookie_params($sessionTime);
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

a mi me funciono esto, lo integre hasta el inicio del php que crear la session del usuario.
Espero que te sirva!

```
$code = rand(100000, 999999);
session_write_close();
session_id($code);
session_set_cookie_params(365*60*60*24);
session_start();
```

Comment: Explica brevemente _qué hace este código_. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.